# Authentication mechanism for low memory, low computing power device

Tags: authentication, zero-knowledge-proofs, reference-request

I am looking for an authentication mechanism that works best with low memory, low computing power devices. I came across a paper "[A Practical Zero-Knowledge Protocol Fitted to Security Microprocessor Minimizing Both Transmission and Memory](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45961-8_11#page-1)" which is released in 1988.

Couldnt find any recent papers. Is it the best one or am I missing some ?

**UPDATE**:

I have a case where I have few processors connected to a gateway processors. I can send upto 64 bits of data at a time. Computing power is low in the sense that I cant employ something like AES-128 algorithm in all chips. I also need to minimize the number of bits of data send for authentication

Comment: You might want to add some more details to your question. For instance, who/what do you want to authenticate to whom, what kind of keys/passwords/tokens do they share, what kind of processor are you talking about ("low" can be relative), and what kind of attack scenarios are you expecting?

Comment: If you can't even do AES _at all_, I'm not sure how you think you're going to implement any kind of zero-knowledge proof. There's very little practical crypto you can do with devices _that_ limited. (Then again, it's also possible that you're just underestimating the performance of your processors; even many smart cards can do AES nowadays.)

Answer (score 2):

SRP doesn't require very much memory, has a low transmission cost (4 packets), and its CPU usage isn't very high (less than 1 second on a low-end 32-bit CPU, but higher on something like an 8-bit CPU).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol

Comment: @skillzeo I cant use this since it require computation at both parties and have to send messages between them many times